# How to check if shapefile is empty using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile

I have a number of shapefiles in a folder but some of them are empty i.e. there are no rows within the shapefile.

Is there a simple way to find those empty shapefiles using ArcPy?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [GetCount](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000n7000000).

```
shapefiles = [r"c:\data.shp", r"c:\data2.shp", r"c:\data3.shp"]
for file in shapefiles:
    if arcpy.management.GetCount(file)[0] == "0":
        print file
```

Comment: If you're all set, use the green arrow to select this answer!